# Average over columns that start with a string using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say I want to average over all columns that start with a string using dplyr. The reason I'm using averaging is not I'm interested in this mean function but to give a simple example since in fact I'm more interested in using more complicated function that takes an unknown number of columns as input. I tried using:

```
iris %>%  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal")), funs(size=mean))
```

but end up getting the same number over all rows. So I tried:

```
iris %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal")), funs(size=mean))
```

but the mean is applied to each entry and therefore not the average that I want. For example for the first row of iris dataset, I would like to get size=(5.1+3.5)/2.

What should I do about this?

---

Update: Following @Ronack's answer, I've made this line of code below.

```
codes <- c("J13","J14",paste0("J", c(seq(150,160))),"J170")

is_in_set <- function(x) {
  return(any(x %in% codes))
}

bd_test <- bd %>% 
  mutate(is_pneumonia = pmap_lgl(select(., starts_with('f.41270.0')), ~is_in_set(c(...))))
```

My debugger shows me the input of my function when I set a breakpoint on my function:

```
Browse[2]> x
  f.41270.0.0   f.41270.0.1   f.41270.0.2   f.41270.0.3   f.41270.0.4   f.41270.0.5   f.41270.0.6   f.41270.0.7   f.41270.0.8   f.41270.0.9 
         1025           938           833           705           797           917          1307          2656          3206          3018 
 f.41270.0.10  f.41270.0.11  f.41270.0.12  f.41270.0.13  f.41270.0.14  f.41270.0.15  f.41270.0.16  f.41270.0.17  f.41270.0.18  f.41270.0.19 
         3701          4656          4659          4398          4294            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA 
 f.41270.0.20  f.41270.0.21  f.41270.0.22  f.41270.0.23  f.41270.0.24  f.41270.0.25  f.41270.0.26  f.41270.0.27  f.41270.0.28  f.41270.0.29 
           NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
```

which really should be

```
> bd %>% select(starts_with("f.41270.0"))%>% head(1)
  f.41270.0.0 f.41270.0.1 f.41270.0.2 f.41270.0.3 f.41270.0.4 f.41270.0.5 f.41270.0.6 f.41270.0.7 f.41270.0.8 f.41270.0.9 f.41270.0.10
1        D467        D619        D696         D70        E831         G10         I10        M478        N189         N19         R931
  f.41270.0.11 f.41270.0.12 f.41270.0.13 f.41270.0.14 f.41270.0.15 f.41270.0.16 f.41270.0.17 f.41270.0.18 f.41270.0.19 f.41270.0.20
1         Y848         Z513         Z538         Z539         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
  f.41270.0.21 f.41270.0.22 f.41270.0.23 f.41270.0.24 f.41270.0.25 f.41270.0.26 f.41270.0.27 f.41270.0.28 f.41270.0.29 f.41270.0.30
1         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
```

These strings are converted to some arbitrary numbers since the 's stays the same. If you make a dataset contains only these above you'll get the same result, so this is a dataset that you can use to reproduce the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowMeans` :

```
iris$size <- rowMeans(iris[grep('^Sepal', names(iris))])
```

If the function is more complex and we can't directly use an inbuilt function like `rowMeans`, we can use `pmap` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris %>% mutate(size = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with('Sepal')), ~mean(c(...))))
```

Comment: Like I said I'm not interested in mean function in particular. I want to apply a more general function. I'm just using mean as an example.

Comment: what is c(...) here? So should I do `~function_name(c(...))` for an arbitrary function?

Comment: Yes, in the second option replace `mean` with your function name.

Comment: I see. So you're saying pmap is the only way there's likely no simpler solution? (e.g. using dplyr only)

Comment: When did I say that `pmap` is the only way? Simple is contextual and subjective. There are other ways as well for eg using `rowwise` or turn the data to long format and applying the function but without knowing more details about your function  it is difficult for me to suggest other alternatives.

Comment: Let's say I have a dataset of codes (column code1,code2,code3) and want to know if there's any of the code from a given set appear. If yes return true if no return false. So I did `mutate(is_in_set = pmap_lgl(select(., starts_with('code')), ~any(unlist(c(...)) %in% set)))` where `set` is a vector of characters. But it gives me false for everything. Am I using your example correctly?

Comment: Looks correct. Try without `unlist`. `mutate(is_in_set = pmap_lgl(select(., starts_with('code')), ~any(c(...) %in% set)))`

Comment: It doesn't work and it seems that the codes are converted to number while they're supposed to be string. Why? Does your c(...) only represent numerical values?

Comment: Sorry, I can't solve it based on imagination. There are 1000's of things which can go wrong. If you include a specific reproducible example I'll be happy to help. Here's a good guide on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I updated the code/example. Do you see why these strings get converted to numbers?

Comment: I've edited the reproducible example once more so that it's minimal. Does this looks understandable to you?

Comment: Sorry, your example is still not reproducible. Please read the link which I shared in my earlier comment to share `dput` of your data. If data is too big use `head` and share first few rows.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't really understand what you are aiming for, but maybe this?

```
   iris %>%
     mutate(size = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Sepal")), na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Like I said I'm not interested in mean function in particular. I want to apply a more general function. I'm just using mean as an example.